# height doesn't show equal on mozilla as per chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have three element in my web page.

1. "Header" with 100px height.
2. "content Area " with 462px height.
3. "Footer" with 100px height.

what happening is on chrome it has got fixed (means scroll bar is invisible which is perfect) but on Mozilla scroll bar is visible don't know why its scrolling on Mozilla when the same code is working fine on chrome... Below is my codes PLEASE HELP ME it happens almost all the times with me.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
    }

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-area {
  min-height: 462px;
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
}

.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<div class="content-area">
  <h2>content area</h2>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <h3>Footer</h3>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
.content-area {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
    }

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-area {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
}

.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content-area">
        <h2>content area</h2>
      </div>
      <footer class="footer">
        <h3>Footer</h3>
      </footer>
```

Comment: its worked but what if we don't know the header and footer height?? it could be anything as per the content